# Reverse an array of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i reverse this array using react native ? i tried `myarray.reverse();` but I get below error message.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'myarray.reverse')

```
const myarray = 
   Array [
      Object {
        "key": "-LrcB3Xcb4QuMtd20TSn",
        "value": Object {
          "question": "26",
          "timestamp": 1571558541642,
          "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
        },
      },
      Object {
        "key": "-LrcB3pf0DQuCr_vfP_2",
        "value": Object {
          "question": "27",
          "timestamp": 1571558542861,
          "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
        },
      },
    ]
```

Comment: it would make sense to share the error-message

Comment: What is that error you're getting?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'myarray.reverse')

Comment: Looks like you use it before definition as long reverse method exists, you variable definition is unknown - it tells undefined.reverse is not possible.

Comment: this doesnt make any sense. Object { ... } is a syntax error in both JS and TS. Array [ ... ] evaluates to `undefined`, and turning this thing into a JSON string and parsing it produces an error as well. Where is this code running?

Comment: It's not clear how this is related to React or Firebase.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful). Right now we're missing too much context, which leads to folks providing answers that apparently don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove Array and Object from the JSON. Works perfect for me.

```
    const myarray = [{
            "key": "-LrcB3Xcb4QuMtd20TSn",
            "value": {
                "question": "26",
                "timestamp": 1571558541642,
                "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
            },
        },
        {
            "key": "-LrcB3pf0DQuCr_vfP_2",
            "value": {
                "question": "27",
                "timestamp": 1571558542861,
                "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
            },
        },
    ]
    myarray.reverse()
```

Comment: the thing is i use an redux firebase api i can only exploit this

Comment: Ok, you should put this in your question itself. Can you share a bit more code?

Comment: what code ? i just have a variable who return this array of object and i want to simply reverse it

Comment: Can you tell us why?

Comment: Sorry I meant the asker's code is not valid JS, mostly because Object { ... } is a syntax error.

Comment: https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/docs/queries.md i use the state.firebase.ordered and

Comment: Do you pick this JSON from some console?

Comment: Consoles sometime show data that make it more readable but it can not be used in code. So you just need to remove Object and array from JSON. In all the JS Frameworks JSON will remain the same as I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Is the pasted code what you are actually getting back from the API?

The formatting/syntax is not correct. As others have stated you shouldn't have the 'Array' and 'Object' words inline like that. I think you're copying code from a terminal/console that added those words in.

If the response actually looks like this you won't have any problem using myaray.reverse()

```
const myarray = [{
            "key": "-LrcB3Xcb4QuMtd20TSn",
            "value": {
                "question": "26",
                "timestamp": 1571558541642,
                "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
            },
        },
        {
            "key": "-LrcB3pf0DQuCr_vfP_2",
            "value": {
                "question": "27",
                "timestamp": 1571558542861,
                "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
            },
        },
    ]
```